# Angular8 application deployment in Azure Service Fabric with nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-cli, azure-service-fabric

I have an angular application that is deployed in Azure service Fabric and working fine. I provided the path in the nginx and it is able to redirect to the proper path. Now I am planning to create individual folders based on the language. 
So previously, I have just one index.html file and 5 bundles in my wwwroot folder. 
But now in my wwwroot folder, I have folders for each language and have these six files in the respective folder.

Previous nginx path

```
    location ~* /StudentAdministration {
http://127.0.0.1:19081/StudentAdministration/StudentAdministrationClient;
```

After my changes

```
        map $http_accept_language $lang {
       default en;
        ~en en;
        ~es es;
        ~fr fr;
    }

    location ~* /StudentAdministration(.*) {
http://127.0.0.1:19081/StudentAdministration/StudentAdministrationClient/$lang$1; 
    }
```

I am able to properly get the lang value using the map function.

When I try to hit url/StudentAdministration it is throwing below error.

Development Mode
Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.

My plan is to just hit the url/StudentAdministration so that it goes to en folder in wwwroot and fetch the index.html and then load the bundles in it. But it is not working.

Comment: Can you highlight the error you are getting? Also can you share the whole `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Could you solve this issue ?

Comment: @sebastienbarbier nope